# getBars getting called recursively infinite times in the JS API for trading view charting_library

Tags: javascript, charts, tradingview-api

I am fairly new to the Trading View's charting library. I have my own custom Datafeed that I want t integrate it with. However, while implementing the JS API for it, the **getBars** method is being called recursively infinite times for some reason.

Here's my code of JS API:

**getBars:**

```
getBars: (symbolInfo, resolution, from=1611030900, to=1611030960, onHistoryCallback, onErrorCallback, firstDataRequest) => {
    fetch('../BT_Data.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(btData => {
        let bars = [];

        btData.forEach(tuple => {
            let timestamp = new Date(tuple.Timestamp);
            let time = Math.floor(timestamp.getTime() / 1000); // Converting it to UNIX timestamp

            bars = [...bars, {
                time: time,
                low: tuple.l,
                high: tuple.h,
                open: tuple.o,
                close: tuple.c,
                volume: tuple.v 
            }]
         })
         onHistoryCallback(bars, { noData: false });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 1):

[TradingView Charting Library](https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/wiki/JS-Api#getbarssymbolinfo-resolution-periodparams-onhistorycallback-onerrorcallback) (link requires GitHub repo membership).

When you get the data using From and To unix epoch time string, you need to set { noData: true } when you dont have requested data available in data feed.

```js
// btData is bars data you get from your data feed
// use from and to parameters to fetch only requested data
// so after one point in time, datafeed will not have any data so at that time, set noData: true like this
    
if(btData.length < 1){
  onHistoryCallback([], { noData: true });
} else {
  onHistoryCallback(bars, { noData: false });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Am also new to trading view. Pretty sure its got to do with the [required countback](https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/wiki/JS-Api#getbarssymbolinfo-resolution-periodparams-onhistorycallback-onerrorcallback)

> It is recommended to consider the priority of countBack higher than the priority of from, i.e. you must return data in the range [from, to), but the number of bars should not be less than countBack. If the number of bars is less than countBack, the chart will call getBars again.

Answer (score 0):

let time = Math.floor(timestamp.getTime() / 1000); // Converting it to UNIX timestamp

don't convert it to unix timstamp
it does not except unix timestamp. it required normal 13 digit timestamp in bars arrray.

getBars() method will be called multiple times untill it gets normal timestamp in array.

this will solve your problem if it does not sovles ping me on discord.
https://discord.com/invite/4pptnAQCqd